# How can I dynamically insert an event based on the date in a calendar using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a table in my database with columns `Date`, `Event`. I want to bind the event based on the date. I try this code. I find some mistakes. Please help me.

```
foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    DateTime dt = r.Field<DateTime>("Date");

    if (e.Day.Date == dt.Date)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = r.Field<string>("Event");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "i find some mistakes" mean? Do you get an error of some kind? What is the message?

Comment: yes.........errors